# How to stretch a text in MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, text, mfc, resize

I have a `CEdit` control on a dialog. I want to write a text in, and to make the edit box resizable, so the text will be stretched or compressed accordingly.

How can I do it?
Is there a control other than `CEdit` which enables this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC does not provide an automated way of handling resizing... there are several additions which can help you. See also:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568/CResizableDialog

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262517/Using-WTLs-Built-in-Dialog-Resizing-Class-for-MFC